# Implement a C++ multiple customer and producer solution with frequently called api, does this work?

Tags: c++, multithreading, producer-consumer

```
// a known api to get ids to buffer
void get_ids(int nums, int * buffer) {};
```

Calling get_ids would cause 1 sec, and I would like to implement a customer and producer model that customer would have to be called and can have the result return in 1 / 5000 per sec. Is any better solution?

```
queue<int> Q;
int * buffer;
mutex mu;
condition_variable cond;

void producer() {
  while (1) {
    if (Q.size() < 5000) {
      unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
      get_ids(5000, buffer);
      for (int i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
        Q.push(buffer[i]);
      }
      locker.unlock();
      cond.notify_all();
    }
  }  
}


int customer() {
  int id;
  unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
  cond.wait(locker, [](){return !Q.empty();});
  id = Q.top();
  Q.pop();
  locker.unlock();
  return id;
}
```

Does this solution work? or would cause any potential problem? Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Was it you that asked the exact same question (almost verbatim) a little while ago? Don't delete and repost your questions. Edit your existing question to improve it instead. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted.

Comment: Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Your code exhibits a data race: it calls `Q.size()` without synchronization, possibly at the same time that `Q.pop()` modifies the queue.

Comment: You have a thread spin in a hot loop, constantly checking the queue size. You are using your CPU as a space heater.

Answer (score 0):

When you read data from queue then you don't need to synchronize it with get_ids.

So if you have only one producer (and multiple consumers) then this modification in producer code should be fine (just move the lock after get_ids):

```
void producer() {
  while (1) {
    if (Q.size() < 5000) {
      get_ids(5000, buffer);
      unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
      for (int i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
        Q.push(buffer[i]);
      }
      locker.unlock();
      cond.notify_all();
    }
  }  
}
```

If you have multiple producers then you need separate mutex to protect access to get_ids (if required) so then you don't block the consumer thread.